# PHP Array of ex:8 item to array of 4 item containing 2-2 Elements of that Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have array like this in PHP :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item] => value
            [item1] => value
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item] => value
            [item1] => value
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [item] => value
            [item1] => value
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [item] => value
            [item1] => value
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [item] => value
            [item1] => value
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [item] => value
            [item1] => value
        )
)
```

and I Have to make it like this to show two item per page

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [item] => value
                    [item1] => value
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [item] => value
                    [item1] => value
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        [2] => Array
            (
                [item] => value
                [item1] => value
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [item] => value
                [item1] => value
            )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
        [4] => Array
            (
                [item] => value
                [item1] => value
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [item] => value
                [item1] => value
            )   
        )

)
```

I have try using array_merge_recursive and few other way but not able to built logic to get above output

Can anyone Help me with this please.

Comment: What happened to element 4?

Comment: You loose some, you gain some :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
array_chunk($array, 2);
```

It should solve your problem

[array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) — Split an array into chunks